# protractor test across multiple files

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

Angular 7 comes with default structure for e2e test looks like follows:

[image]

How Can I organise my tests in multiple files.
for example

[image]

I want to avoid having so long testing files and these businees units have nothing to do with its others.

***Question***: how can I split my protractor test, into multiple files and folder and how can I run them after

***Environment***: Angular 7.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to have `src` directory under e2e directory and have the structure as you defined. Then, just change `specs` variable in `protractor.conf.js` file to `'./**/*.e2e-spec.ts'`. Angular application will run all the e2e tests, one by one just like how it does for unit tests files.

### Solution:

```
exports.config = {
  ...
  specs: [
    './**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  ...
};
```